# Combination of 2 data frames

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes, `d(date,a,b,c,number1,number2)` and `e(a,b,c,population)` where a,b,c are gender, state and categorie of age.

rem : the number of lines of d > the number of lines of e

I would like to add the good amount of pupulation from e corresponding to the same a and b and c in the dataframe d, ie `d(date,a,b,c,number1,number2,population)`

What I tried : (didn't work)

```
result <- merge (d,e,by=c(a,b,c))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left join:

```
result <- merge(d, e, by = c("a", "b", "c"), all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer diaspv, but it gives me a data frame result bigger than the d one. And I would like to have the same number of line (obs) for result and d.

Comment: Without a reproducible example it is more difficult to assist you. The relationship between your tables is probably one-to-many. Group the data in the second table to achieve the desired result.

Comment: my bad, just realized that my data frame e is wrong, first time working with big files and I didn't check it.. thanks for your support :)